# How to add to my map field in Cloud Firestore using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is from the docs.

```
{
name: "Frank",
favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" },
age: 12}

// To update favorite color:
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
   "favorites.color": "Red"
})
```

I want to know how can I add to the favorites field not just update a value. Let's say I want to add

```
[size: "large"]
```

to the favorites map. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The term 'update' in the API here means that you're *updating* a document, but you can *add* fields to that document. So this should work

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
   "favorites.size": "large"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
db.collection("users").document("frank").set(
   {favorites: {size: "large"}},
   {merge: true}
)
```

The important part is `merge: true` as will specify that the data should be merged into the existing document

Comment: No I haven't. But would it be easier if I just made favorites an array of dictionaries and just add and remove from it that way?

Comment: I think it will be good as well! Have you tried to make it an array of dict? Don't forget `merge: true` to `append`